# How can i login to Microsoft Graph from Unity project?

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, graph, oauth

I would like to login to Azure services using Microsoft Graph from Unity project. There does not seem to be much examples or tutorials how to do this in Unity or they are way old that i found from google?

Is there any Unity packages or tutorials, examples or articles about this to help me to  right direction? I cant be only one who wants to make app authentication and login using Azure, to Unity project?

I have everything ready in Azure´s end and i have c# example that connects to Azure but that script example is more like ready c# application and seems quite complex to transfer as part of Unity project or i am lacking skills to do that, or both.

Comment: Could you please refer this Article https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/integrate-the-microsoft-graph-in-your-hololens-and-mixed-reality/ba-p/318143